# HikariCP: Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0) => Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hikaricp

Help me to understand and solve this error. I've been trying to figure out different options for days/weeks now.
I probably read everything that is on the Internet and tried all kinds of options and combinations. HikariCP refuses to work as expected.

So, I have HikariCP-5.0.1 and MySQL 8.1

Pods are located in Kubernetes in different namespaces. There are no proxies, firewalls or service meshes between them. And they are on the one single node.
I run a task that runs 20-30 minutes. That is, at startup there is a connection to the database, then the logic works, and then I need to save the results in the database. It's simple case.

### In the debug output I can see that Hikari pings the database every 30 seconds and says that everything is ok.

```bash
06:35:52.890 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG [       com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:414.logPoolState()] - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0) 
06:35:52.890 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG [       com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:521.fillPool()] - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool has sufficient level or currently being filled (queueDepth=0).
```

### Here are the HIkariCP settings in Spring Autoconfiguration:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://mysql.mysql:3306/dev
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.hikari.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.maxAllowedPacket=534773760
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.allowPublicKeyRetrieval=YES
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useSSL=NO
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1

#This is my experiments, which i set in different combinations and values. Но данный пример я описываю со значениями, которые активны. Здесь только закомментированный пример.
#To hold connection
#spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=120000
#spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=864000000
#spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.autoReconnect=true
#Keep connection for 10 days
#spring.datasource.hikari.keepalive-time=864000000
#spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=864000000
#spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=864000000
```

### Here are the HikariCP settings in debug mode:

```bash
06:33:21.946 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:968.attemptFromContextLoader()] - Driver class org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver found in Thread context class loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7291c18f 
06:33:21.961 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:968.attemptFromContextLoader()] - Driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver found in Thread context class loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@7291c18f 
06:33:22.070 [main] INFO  [rg.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper:31.logPersistenceUnitInformation()] - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 
Waiting for starting Guardius Owasp Worker Agent...
06:33:22.132 [main] INFO  [                   org.hibernate.Version:44.logVersion()] - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final 
06:33:22.491 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1100.logConfiguration()] - HikariPool-1 - configuration: 
06:33:22.493 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - allowPoolSuspension.............false 
06:33:22.493 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - autoCommit......................true 
06:33:22.493 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - catalog.........................none 
06:33:22.493 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - connectionInitSql...............none 
06:33:22.494 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - connectionTestQuery............."SELECT 1" 
06:33:22.494 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - connectionTimeout...............30000 
06:33:22.494 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - dataSource......................none 
06:33:22.494 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - dataSourceClassName.............none 
06:33:22.495 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - dataSourceJNDI..................none 
06:33:22.495 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - dataSourceProperties............{maxAllowedPacket=534773760, password=<masked>, allowPublicKeyRetrieval=YES, useSSL=NO} 
06:33:22.495 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - driverClassName................."com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" 
06:33:22.495 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - exceptionOverrideClassName......none 
06:33:22.496 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - healthCheckProperties...........{} 
06:33:22.496 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - healthCheckRegistry.............none 
06:33:22.496 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - idleTimeout.....................600000 
06:33:22.496 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - initializationFailTimeout.......1 
06:33:22.497 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - isolateInternalQueries..........false 
06:33:22.497 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:mysql://mysql.mysql:3306/dev 
06:33:22.497 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - keepaliveTime...................0 
06:33:22.497 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - leakDetectionThreshold..........0 
06:33:22.497 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - maxLifetime.....................1800000 
06:33:22.498 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - maximumPoolSize.................10 
06:33:22.498 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - metricRegistry..................none 
06:33:22.498 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - metricsTrackerFactory...........none 
06:33:22.498 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - minimumIdle.....................10 
06:33:22.498 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - password........................<masked> 
06:33:22.498 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - poolName........................"HikariPool-1" 
06:33:22.498 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - readOnly........................false 
06:33:22.499 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - registerMbeans..................false 
06:33:22.499 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - scheduledExecutor...............none 
06:33:22.499 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - schema..........................none 
06:33:22.499 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - threadFactory...................internal 
06:33:22.499 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - transactionIsolation............default 
06:33:22.500 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - username........................"dev" 
06:33:22.500 [main] DEBUG [          com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig:1132.logConfiguration()] - validationTimeout...............5000 
06:33:22.500 [main] INFO  [      com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:110.getConnection()] - HikariPool-1 - Starting... 
06:33:22.720 [main] INFO  [       com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:565.checkFailFast()] - HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@61e7bf2f 
06:33:22.722 [main] INFO  [      com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:123.getConnection()] - HikariPool-1 - Start completed. 
06:33:22.744 [main] INFO  [                             SQL dialect:66.logSelectedDialect()] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
06:33:22.822 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG [       com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:414.logPoolState()] - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=1, active=0, idle=1, waiting=0) 
.....
06:33:22.939 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG [       com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:414.logPoolState()] - HikariPool-1 - After adding stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
```

### Here is my my.cnf:

```ini
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
skip-name-resolve
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
basedir=/opt/bitnami/mysql
plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib/plugin
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
datadir=/bitnami/mysql/data
tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
max_allowed_packet=512M
bind-address=*
pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid
log-error=/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log
character-set-server=UTF8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
slow_query_log=0
slow_query_log_file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log
long_query_time=10.0
default-time-zone = '+02:00'
wait_timeout=2592000
interactive_timeout=2592000

[client]
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set=UTF8
plugin_dir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/lib/plugin

[manager]
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
pid-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysqld.pid
```

### Here are the results of the database queries:

**show global variables LIKE "%timeout%";**
[image]

**show global variables LIKE "%wait%";**
[image]

**show global variables LIKE "%conn%";**
[image]

### Here is the complete Stacktrace::

```bash
06:53:46.114 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9999-exec-2] WARN  [  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection:177.checkException()] - HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@61e7bf2f marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08S01), ErrorCode(0) 

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,214,276 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,214,276 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2050)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:401)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at io.my.services.StorageService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.saveReport(<generated>)
    at io.my.services.ReportService.persistsReports(ReportService.java:110)
    at io.my.services.MyActiveScanService.activeScan(MyActiveScanService.java:219)
    at io.my.controllers.MyController.activeAttack(MyController.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1,214,276 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1,214,276 milliseconds ago.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:581)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:761)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:700)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:1051)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:997)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2033)
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:789)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:1025)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:107)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:150)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:180)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:119)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeaderLocal(SimplePacketReader.java:81)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:575)
    ... 86 common frames omitted
06:53:46.116 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG [         com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase:132.quietlyCloseConnection()] - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@61e7bf2f: (connection is broken) 
06:53:46.167 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG [       com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:738.call()] - HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@28017506 
06:53:50.118 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9999-exec-2] ERROR [my.services.MyActiveScanService:226.activeScan()] - =#= Execution Error. RunId=53. Error=Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at io.my.services.StorageService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.saveReport(<generated>)
    at io.my.services.ReportService.persistsReports(ReportService.java:110)
    at io.my.services.MyActiveScanService.activeScan(MyActiveScanService.java:219)
    at io.my.controllers.MyController.activeAttack(MyController.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at 

....

org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:421)
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:502)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy127.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:401)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.begin(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:72)
    ... 77 common frames omitted
```

### Here is the application start and its end time.

```
startedAt: '2023-10-02T04:33:05Z'
finishedAt: '2023-10-02T04:53:52Z'
```

Almost 21 minutes in total.

As you can see from the stacktrace message, the last successful connection to the database was **1,214,276 milliseconds ago**, which is equivalent to **20.2379 minutes**.

And I think that this is some kind of incomprehensible bug, because I have a running application for clients and it works great, there are no glitches. With the same settings and versions.

I would be grateful for your help. I have already seen many similar topics on the Internet and here, but not a single proposed solution helped.

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen this error when from the server side (MySQL), the connection is closed, and that connection is still there in the free pool and tried to be used. Have you tried setting "test-on-borrow" flag to true? So that a connection from the free pool is tested before returning to the thread for usage? If found invalid, then removed from the free pool and if all are invalid, then a new connection will be opened and returned.

Comment: In this case, the operation would only fail if all the connections have been invalidated, and the new connections to the DB server are also not opening.

Comment: That 20-30 minutes of processing - does that actively use the same DB connection? Is it possible that you are neither releasing the connection back to the free pool nor actively using it for a long period?

Comment: @Ishan Thanks for the answer and suggestion. No, I do not test with "test-on-borrow". Do HikariCP has such config? I did not find it.

Comment: @Ishan Thanks again. 
I think the same connection is being used. This is visible in debug mode.
And as I wrote, I do not perform any operations on the database. Only at the end of execution.

Comment: "That is, at startup there is a connection to the database, then the logic works, and then I need to save the results in the database. It's simple case." - so on start-up just a DB Pool is created, or you are also borrowing a connection from Hikari? And keeping it idle for 20-30 minutes without using it, and then just using it at the end? Can you just create the pool but not get a connection from it? Just borrow a connection at the end when the process needs it. If you also need one connection at the beginning, then just give it back to the pool and get again at the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870473/hikari-and-test-on-borrow-option - And yes, test-on-borrow flag is not needed now. It is part of Hikari by default when you borrow a connection. But after borrowing if it remains with your own thread for a long long time, then Hikari cannot do anything. So, borrow and return frequently as soon as work is done. Rather than borrowing and keeping for a long long time.

Comment: Maybe have 2 separate `@Transactional` methods in the beginning and at the end, and one non-transactional in the middle to do the 20-30 minutes of the process without any borrowed DB connection from Hikari.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answers.
I roughly understand what you are talking about.
I just don’t understand a little how I can manage all this.
The main idea of Spring autoconfiguration is that you enter the settings and it works. This case works for me with another application, there has never been anything similar there.

Comment: At startup, a connection is created. Relatively speaking, I save the start time in the database and then launch the process itself. Yes, after the start there is 1 request to the database.

Comment: If we look at this case in detail, it turns out that this connection (which was executed at startup) hangs in the pool. But it is already closed for the database. Why doesn't HickariCP close this connection itself? Ok, no problem for me to close it. Only hibernate/Spring Data JPA does all this. I haven’t seen any examples anywhere that something needs to be done in this direction. Or maybe this is my case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64682207/1590594

Comment: @Ishan "So, borrow and return frequently as soon as work is done. Rather than borrowing and keeping for a long long time." How?

Comment: "Maybe have 2 separate @Transactional methods in the beginning and at the end, and one non-transactional in the middle to do the 20-30 minutes of the process without any borrowed DB connection from Hikari." I didn't understand you a bit. On every database Query-method I have  "@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)". Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: "But it is already closed for the database. Why doesn't HickariCP close this connection itself? " - That's the main motto of using Connection Pool. Connections are NOT to be physically closed and to be kept open in a 'free' pool, so that another thread that needs to work with DB can get it and no time is wasted for physically opening a new connection to the DB. If you directly physically close the connection from your end, the Pool won't know about it. So from your end, you should only release to the pool, and not close it. If it is closed on the DB side, it means something is wrong.

Comment: "On every database Query-method I have "@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)". Maybe this is a problem?" - It may or may not be. Check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation for behavior of different propagations. REQUIRES_NEW will suspend any existing transaction (if any) and create a new one. But if there is an outer method that also has @Transactional and that method calls these other methods that have REQUIRES_NEW - outer method would have already opened a transaction.

Comment: Make sure that the 20-30 minutes of processing that does not need any DB activity is NEITHER marked as `@Transactional` itself NOR called from any @Transactional methods. This will make sure that at least for those 20-30 minutes no connection is kept allocated, but unused.

Comment: @Ishan I have already removed all transaction annotations. No more anywhere.
The situation is the same, nothing helps.
I understand all the logic why it doesn’t work and so on..
But where to look? What to look for? I have set all kinds of parameters that should be set in the database and showed all the settings that are in the database in the screenshots.
What else should I check? The strangest thing is that another application works with the same parameters without problems.

Comment: Hi @Ishan thanks a lot for your explanations and support. I solved it. Found the key. It is of course not a DB or Hikari. It is Spring. ))) The key is "spring.jpa.open-in-view=false" and Wrap methods with Transacionals and everything is working as should and as expected.

Comment: Welcome. I wasn't much of a help though. Good catch.

Comment: And reading about "spring.jpa.open-in-view" - it opens a transaction in the view layer. So, even if you are not having `@Transactional` that session is open for your entire process - including those 20-30 minutes of processing, and for that entire period of time, the DB connection is allocated and unused, and I think, not being checked for being 'alive' every few seconds.

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain. If you think alone, then after a while you start to run out of ideas, but if you think with someone, then you can constantly think about the case from the discussion context. Thank you!